# What does the $\gamma$$c$ term in the temporal component of the 4-velocity equation represent exactly?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, velocity

What does the $\gamma$$c$ term in the temporal component of the [4-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) equation represent exactly? Moreover, what does it mean conceptually when the velocity term in the gamma function is equal to the speed of light or say even 99.9999999% the speed of light in $\gamma$$c$? $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}c$$

Comment: I hope someone gives a better answer. Mine is that actually 4-momentum is a more interesting quantity. In which case the top component is energy/c, and the gamma factor tells you how much the energy is increased over mc^2 because of the object's motion. 4-velocity is a 4 vector only because it's 4-momentum divided by rest mass (dividing a 4 vector by a constant gives you a new 4-vector).

Answer (score 1):

The 4-velocity, $\vec{u}$, is the derivative of the 4-position, $\vec{s}$, with respect to proper time $\vec{u} = \frac{d\vec{s}}{d\tau}$.  The complete position 4-vector is $(ct, x, y, z)$.  The inclusion of $c$ in the $t$-component ensures that all four components have dimensions of length.  That is to say that they are all measured in same units.

When you take the derivative of the $t$-component you get
$$u_t = c\frac{dt}{d\tau} = c\gamma.$$
The Lorentz factor is the relative rate of the passage of coordinate time $t$ compared proper time $\tau$.  The factor of $c$ remains as effectively a unit conversion, ensuring each component has dimensions of velocity.

Comment: thanks, but what physically does $\gamma$$c$ represent? Does it mean that everything at rest is moving through time at the speed of light thus for an object increasing its velocity through space, from that moving object's pov it begins to move faster than the speed of light through time relative to objects still at rest in the universe which are only moving through time at the speed of light?

Answer (score 1):

1. The term represents the energy per unit mass
2. In theories obeying special relativity, a massive particle can never have $v=c$. And phrases like '99.99% the speed of light' mean $v=0.9999c$

Answer (score 0):

It represents time dilation.

Each observer moves along their own worldline. If an object is moving and we are measuring its 4-velocity, the only observer who has the same time coordinate as the proper time of the object is the observer that moves with the object.

Therefore for the observer moving with the object, the time-component is always $c$. More specifically the 4-velocity in this intertial reference frame is $\dot x^\mu = (c, 0, 0, 0)$.

Everyone else has to account for the definition of the 4-velocity being defined in terms of $\tau$, whereas they are using variables $t,x,y,z$ in their Minkowski space. Since $t$ and $\tau$ do *not* tick at the same rate, we get the factor $dt/d\tau = \gamma$.

So in a sense it is just a mathematical result (e.g. why have Christoffel's components got this numerical factor etc, in a sense it is just a result of the abstract definition falling in to place). But intuitively it is because we have defined 4-velocity to be with respect to the proper time of the object (there are good reasons for this in terms of defining curvature and acceleration appropriately in a 4-dimensional Minkwoskian space), so we have to account for that conversion rate between our clock and theirs.

Comment: thanks, but what physically does $\gamma$$c$ represent? Does it mean that everything at rest is moving through time at the speed of light thus for an object increasing its velocity through space, from that moving object's pov it begins to move faster than the speed of light through time relative to objects still at rest in the universe which are only moving through time at the speed of light?

Comment: Not sure why you are talking about moving at the speed of light. Just think of $c$ as a conversion factor so that time can have the same units as space. Also focus on this inertial reference frame idea. Can you follow that they will record their own four velocity as simply $\dot x^\mu = (c, 0, 0, 0)$?

Comment: "Not sure why you are talking about moving at the speed of light" Because the 4-velocity says you are always moving at the speed of light through spacetime. And yes, the speed of light is a conversion factor that gives the dimension of time length. However, when you make proper time $\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}\Delta t$ a derivative of $c\Delta$$t$ now the dimension of time takes on a velocity $\gamma$$c$. Ergo when you are at rest the 4-velocity (the 4-vector) says you are moving through time at the $c$

Comment: Ok in a sense yes, but this is not the normal way to think of speed. If by speed you mean that the rest observer's clock ticks at a rate of 1 tick per $c$ seconds then you are correct. This is trivial though since their position worldline in their rest frame is simply $x^\mu = (ct,0,0,0)$

Comment: No, not in a sense. What I stated is precisely what the 4-velocity (4-vector) represents - that everything is constantly moving through spacetime at the speed of light. Also, my original question was - "What does the $\gamma$$c$ term in the temporal component of the 4-velocity equation represent exactly?". What does the 4-position $x^\mu = (ct,0,0,0)$ have to do with it?

Comment: The position is where the speed comes from. Are you familiar with the definition of the 4-velocity?

Comment: I literally stated what the 4-velocity represent in spacetime in my previous post. So, I can only imagine that you 're asking if I'm familiar with the definition of the 4-velocity in some attempt to disprove what I wrote. And again, what does the 4-position have to do with my initial question, which was what does the $\gamma$$c$ term in the temporal component of the 4-velocity equation represent exactly?

Comment: Well the definition of 4-velocity is that it is the rate of change of 4-position, so in answer to "what does it have to do with my question", I'm working from the first-principle of tracking back the factor $\gamma$ from the definition of 4-velocity. True my answer did not derive this, but a Lorentz transformation between the rest frame and the observation frame would show it trivially.